# «Да, это дивная вещь!» — это единственная запись голоса Рубинштейна?

Tags: история

Вопрос, скорее, по истории. И тем не менее.

«Да, это дивная вещь!» — это единственная запись голоса Рубинштейна?

Инф-ция по теме: https://arzamas.academy/mag/157-chaikovsky

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта.